# how to add a column in java jdbc

Tags: java, sqlite

I want to add a column in java `jdbc` This is my code.and It create a error,and I don't know why

```
String addcol_str="alter table person add "+date+" text";

 ResultSet rs=stat.executeQuery(addcol_str);
```

stat is the statement

Comment: i will feel very honored if someone can help me !

Comment: Could you post what the error is?

Comment: What is the type and value of 'date'?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stat.executeUpdate(addcol_str)` for altering a table because it does not result a `resultSet`